# Trying to use YouTube API to check views of a video every hour. Can Python be used to store the data or is PHP needed?

Tags: python, php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I apologize if this is a naive question as I'm a learning developer. I'm trying to come up a project to work on in the summer to build my portfolio as a Python developer and as of right now I'm in the planning stages and just want to know if I'm on the right track.

But without going into the specifics, I essentially want to get the meta data from one YouTube video every hour from the time it was uploaded and the current time and make a time vs views/hour plot using the YouTube API and display it on a website

I've looked into webscrapers, but from my understanding, those scripts can only take one instance at a time.

Would I need to learn PHP as well in order to store the data from each instance the API is called? Or is there a way to do what I'm thinking of natively in Python?

If so would I need to know it extensively?

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 - YouTube API only returns a total viewCount. You won't be able to ask for a video's viewCount from 6 hours ago, for example. However, you can call the API every hour for the video viewCount and store the numbers yourself going forward.

Part 2 - PHP vs Python doesn't matter. You can store data with either code.